# Swift Closure Value Capture scope

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift3, ios10

I have a question using Swift 3, I am trying to access the task variable from inside my completion closure but it is not available.  If I try to access "task" inside the block I get "error: use of unresolved identifier 'task'" What am I doing wrong?

```
typealias completionHandler = (data: Data?, httpResponse: HTTPURLResponse?, validServer: Bool, serverRealm: String?, serverVersion: String?) -> Void
typealias failureHandler = (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void


func ping(address: String, completionBlock: completionHandler, failureBlock: failureHandler?) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
    guard var addressComponents = URLComponents(string: address) else {
        let error = NSError(domain: "PING", code: 99, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Invalid URL: \(address)"])
        failureBlock?(data: nil, response: nil, error: error)
        return nil
    }
    addressComponents.path = Paths.ping.rawValue
    let request = URLRequest(url: addressComponents.url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: gsTimeout)

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Ping the server and process the repsonse
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var task: URLSessionDataTask!
    task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    print("Task: \(task)")
        if error == nil {
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                let results = self.parseHeader(response)
                print("Results: \(results)")
                if results.isServer == true {
                    completionBlock(data: data, httpResponse: response, validServer: results.isServer, serverRealm: results.realm, serverVersion: results.serverVersion)
                } 
            }
        } else {
            failureBlock?(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        }
    }

    task.taskDescription = Paths.ping.rawValue
    task.resume()
    return task
}
```

Updated with working code now.  task is available if you use it inside the block.  Thanks everyone

Comment: Where's your `completionBlock` definition? It's not clear by the code you provided how it will get the `task`.

Comment: That completion block is from the API " func dataTask(with: URL, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void)"

Comment: Please show more context. Where does this code live? Also why are you declaring the `var task` and initializing it with `task =` on two different lines?

Comment: It should work if you declare task as `var task: URLSessionDataTask!`

Comment: Ah. So this is not a compile error at all! It's just that you don't understand how to use _the debugger_. This has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Dan, tried that still did not work, updated the question is a pic of the console area.  I have a breakpoint on the  line "if error == nil"

Comment: Yeah, your code itself has to capture the variable at compile time for it to be available to the debugger.

Comment: Matt, any code that references task fails inside that block.

Comment: @Rob you are doing a very bad job of asking this question. You keep changing it supplying new info which completely changes what the question is. I suggest you take a deep breath and rewrite the question to ask the _real_ question! If it isn't about the `po` and the code you showed, why did you show the `po` and that code?

Comment: Got it now.  My question was how to see the captured value of task inside the block.  I was mistakenly stopping the program inside the block and trying to view the value of task, but I added a print to test if I could see the value and that worked.  Sorry for the confusion and I see it now.  My apologies if I offended you somehow.

Comment: Not at all, just trying to help you by getting you to ask the question to which you really wanted to know the answer! Very hard to get meaningful help otherwise.  You'll notice that your original question _never mentioned `po` in the debugger_. So the whole point of the question was being completely omitted. Looks like you got it cleared up, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It compiles just fine.

You are unable to `po` the value of `task` using LLDB while paused in the debugger because you are paused inside the completion block. You never captured `task` in this code (you didn't refer to it), so it is not in scope here. Only outside scope *actually referred to* inside a closure is captured by the closure.

Comment: You can't do this if you want to use `task` inside the block, it has to be initialized before the block can capture it.

Comment: Changing to var task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask // ...
did not work either.

Comment: @dan He doesn't use `task` inside the block

Comment: Ahh, that's it.  Adding a simple print("Task = \(task)") inside the block worked!